# Kubernetes [error: no kind "CertificateSigningRequest"]

Tags: docker, kubernetes, virtualbox, minikube

While I am trying to approve the certificate for RBAC in Kubernetes I am getting error.

I create a certificate request for Kubernetes for student-csr

```
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: student-csr
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: <encoded key>
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - client auth
```

Then I ran `kubectl create -f signing-request.yaml` and out put was

```
certificatesigningrequest.certificates.k8s.io/student-csr created
```

And then `kubectl get csr` shows

```
NAME          AGE    SIGNERNAME                     REQUESTOR       CONDITION
student-csr   100s   kubernetes.io/legacy-unknown   minikube-user   Pending
```

So far so good. But the problem occurred when I tried to approve it by `kubectl certificate approve student-csr`

```
No resources found
error: no kind "CertificateSigningRequest" is registered for version "certificates.k8s.io/v1" in scheme "k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/scheme/scheme.go:28"
```

I don't have any idea why. I tried to search but there is nothing similar to this kind of error.

Tools I am using:

- Minikube: v1.13.1
- Kubernetes v1.19.2
- Docker 19.03.12
- Mac OS: Catalina (10.15.6)

*** Using minikube with `minikube start --container-runtime=docker --vm-driver=virtualbox`

Any kind of help much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9):

I faced this issue while I was running kubectl version v1.17 and my k8s cluster was version v1.19:

```
$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.17.0
Server Version: v1.19.2
```

I fixed it by [updating my kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/) to v1.19

```
$ kubectl version --short
 Client Version: v1.19.0
 Server Version: v1.19.2
```

Answer (score 2):

In the [Kubernetes v1.19 release notes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/) you can find the following changes:

> **The `CertificateSigningRequest` API is promoted to `certificates.k8s.io/v1`** with the following changes:
>
> - `spec.signerName` is now required, and requests for `kubernetes.io/legacy-unknown` are not allowed to be created via the
>   `certificates.k8s.io/v1` API
> - `spec.usages is` now required, may not contain duplicate values, and must only contain known usages
> - `status.conditions` may not contain duplicate types
> - `status.conditions[*].status` is now required
> - `status.certificate` must be PEM-encoded, and contain only CERTIFICATE blocks (#91685, @liggitt) [SIG API Machinery,
>   Architecture, Auth, CLI and Testing]

So the error you see:

```
no kind "CertificateSigningRequest" is registered for version "certificates.k8s.io/v1"
```

means that you should be using **`apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1`** instead of `apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1`.

In order to change your API versions you can use the [`kubectl convert`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#convert) command:

> Convert config files between different API versions. Both YAML and
> JSON formats are accepted.
>
> The command takes filename, directory, or URL as input, and convert it
> into format of version specified by `--output-version` flag. If target
> version is not specified or not supported, convert to latest version.

Comment: No luck so far. I tried your suggestions. And I even try the sample given on the Kubernetes site. But still same error.

Comment: @atiq1589 Could you share your new `CertificateSigningRequest`configs by editing your question? Have you tried to use the `kubectl convert` command as I advised?

Answer (score 1):

You might have skipped the configuring *cgroup* driver step when installing *kubeadm*
Check out this resource: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#configuring-a-cgroup-driver

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have two version of csr. Change your student-csr version to certificates.k8s.io/v1 , it will work I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The certificates controller is not enabled by default in Minikube, there is an opened issue : https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1647

This is the reason why you can create your API object but cannot approve the certificate.

However, it may be possible to make it work using extra params :
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1647#issuecomment-311138886

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue as you with my minikube (minikube v1.24.0). Kubectl was not the reason of the error:

```
kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.22.3
Server Version: v1.22.3
```

Got the same error as you mentioned:

```
error: unable to recognize "*****.yml": no matches for kind "CertificateSigningRequest" in version "certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

I solved the problem with changing the **apiVersion** and adding **signerName** items in my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
to
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
```

Successfully applied final maniefst file version is as below:

```
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: mycsr
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: <BASE64_CSR>
  signerName: kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - server auth
  - client auth
```